# Docker with 2 wordpress and 1 database issue

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I want to do the following :
1 wordpress on port 8000
1 wordpress on port 8001
1 db shared for the 2 wordpress sites

HEre the docker I have imagined

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   wordpress-mikael-blog:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     container_name: mikael-blog
     ports:
       - "8001:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: mikael_
   wordpress-audrey-blog:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     container_name: audrey-blog
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: audrey
volumes:
    db_data:
```

The docker-compose up is ok and I see the 3 images :

```
STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp   mikael-blog
Up 22 hours         0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   audrey-blog
Up 22 hours         3306/tcp               wordpressplatform_db_1
```

But then I don't know why the localhost:8001 is redirecting me to localhost:8000.

I get an HTTP 301 redirection. I think this is a Wordpress issue but I am not sure right now so I am not deleting the questions yet.

Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

From your yaml file, i could see that both wordpress containers are exposed to `port 80`. Try to use different ports on the container.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after  I restarted everything worked fine 'as is'.

I cannot find an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Tested today, this config file works fine for me:

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - example1
      - example2
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example1.blog/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/example1
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example2.blog/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/example2
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example1.blog/privkey.pem:/var/www/html/example1/ssl/privkey.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example1.blog/fullchain.pem:/var/www/html/example1/ssl/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.blog/privkey.pem:/var/www/html/example2/ssl/privkey.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.blog/fullchain.pem:/var/www/html/example2/ssl/fullchain.pem
    networks:
      - websites


  example1:
    image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
    depends_on:
      - db_example1
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: example1.blog/wordpress/.env
    container_name: example1
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example1.blog/wordpress/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example1.blog/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/example1
    # command: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
    networks:
      - websites

  example2:
    image: wordpress:fpm-alpine
    depends_on:
      - db_example2
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: example2.blog/wordpress/.env
    container_name: example2
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example2.blog/wordpress/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example2.blog/wordpress/html:/var/www/html/example2
    # command: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
    networks:
      - websites

  db_example1:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: db_example1
    env_file: example1.blog/wordpress/.env
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example1.blog/wordpress/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    networks:
      - websites

  db_example2:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: db_example2
    env_file: example2.blog/wordpress/.env
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sites/example2.blog/wordpress/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    networks:
      - websites
networks:
  websites: {}
```

Besides, I didn't care about the resources lost by creating two DBs, which can be promoted.